# Mysql inserting id as 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, create-table

I am trying to make a revisions page, but when I insert a new revision, it sets the id to 0 instead of 1 more than the last entry, so I can make 1 new revision, but no more. Here is my mySQL code:

```
("INSERT INTO `revisions` (version, author, content, `date`) VALUES ('".$version."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$content."', '".$date."')");
```

**Edit:**
Wow that was embarrassing... I made the table id default 0...
**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE `revisions` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `version` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Show us your table schema.

Comment: Make sure A_I is enabled in your mySQL table

Answer (score 5):

:) it saids clearly

> `id` int(11) NOT NULL **DEFAULT '0'**

it will be inserted as default value 0 if you dont make any value , then it will be 0 as default.

if you wanna be 1 as default then use this

> id int(11) NOT NULL **DEFAULT '1'**

or if you want it be incremented then use this

> id int(11) NOT NULL **AUTO_INCREMENT**

//this will be automatically 1,2,3,4,...values incremented everytime you inseret new value

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `revisions` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
......
```

you need to set id with auto increment

check out the mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` to your `id` instead. That way, it'll just increment automatically (as the name suggests) each time you insert a row.

```
CREATE TABLE `revisions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
```